# Как закрыть статическое модальное окно bootstrap

Tags: html, bootstrap, modal

Есть статическое модальное окно, то есть я его не вызываю по кнопке а вывожу статически

HTML:

```
<div class="modal fade in display-block" tabindex="-1">

<div class="modal-dialog">

    <div class="modal-content">

        <div class="modal-body">

            <div class="text-center">
                <div class="icon-object border-success text-success"><i class="icon-checkmark4"></i></div>
                <h5 class="no-margin-bottom">{$title}</h5>
                <p>{$description}</p>
            </div>

        </div>

        <div class="modal-footer text-center">
            <button type="button" class="btn bg-success" data-dismiss="modal">Ок!</button>
        </div>

    </div>

</div>
```

Чтоб оно было видимым я добавил класс `dispalay-block`

Как по кнопке его закрыть?

Answer (score 1):

Показывайте окно не через добавление класса, а стандартным вызовом `$('.modal').modal('show')`; и тогда кнопки с data-атрибутами будут работать из коробки.

Answer (score 0):

Вариантов немало. Самый простой на jquery:

```
$('.close_button').on('click', function () {
    $('.modal.display-block').removeClass("display-block);
});
```

Или на голом js:

```
document.querySelector('.close_button').onclick = function () {
    document.querySelector('.modal.display-block').classList.remove("display-block");
};
```